# Вставить после нужного мне элемента в массиве тире, пример: 1920 - 2020

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив, и всё никак не получается вставить тире между годами, чтобы было понятно что выбрал не только 1920,2020 года а выбрать именно промежуток 1920-2020

[image: Массив]

Comment: при заполнении массива не разносите данные в 2 колонки а записывайте в одну с разделителем, или при обработке делайте объединение с тире.. я не пойму зачем вам там тире нужно...

Comment: Эти данные я получаю с объекта, перебираю его через Object.keys, и как бы 1920 это year_from а 2020 это year_to, это 2 разные ключа и я никак не могу их объединить в 1 колонку.

Comment: это и так видно.. зачем вам тире то? при обработке данных объединяйте их и всё, не нужно там тире никакое лепить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var arr = ['CARS', 'AUDI', 1920, 2020, 'State', 'Arizona', 'Collision'];

let test = arr.join(',').replace(/(\d+),(\d+)/, '$1-$2').split(',');
console.log(test);
```

Ну или такой вариант:

```js
var arr = ['CARS', 'AUDI', 1920, 2020, 'State', 'Arizona', 'Collision'];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(arr[i])) {
        arr[i] = arr[i]+'-'+arr[i+1];
        delete arr[i+1];
    }
}

console.log(arr.filter(n => n));
```

Answer (score 0):

вот вариант, если значения массива известны.

```
["a","b",1,2,"h","j"].join(",").split(",1,2,").join(",1-2,").split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в вашем случае можно попробовать вот что:

```js
let arr = ['CARS', 'AUDI', 1920, 2020, 'State', 'Arizona', 'Collision'] // Если я правильно понял, у вас только 2 значения типа Number
let year_index;
for (element of arr) {
    if (!isNaN(+element)) { // Унарный оператор "+" возвращает NaN, если применяется к строке
        year_index = arr.indexOf(element);
        break;
    }
}
let chunk = arr.splice(year_index + 1); // "Отрываем" от массива всё, что идёт после первого года
arr.push('-', ...chunk); // Добавляем в конец оставшейся части массива дефис и отделённый ранее "кусок"
console.log(arr);
```

оператор "..." ([spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax))

Comment: Изначально дал неправильный ответ. Переписал код.